# Twig formatting numbers in symfony

Tags: numbers, twig, symfony4

I receive from my database numbers that sometimes have two digits after comma and sometimes only one, i want to force the display of my number at 2 digits after commas, is there a filter for that in twig ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way after a long struggle with myself...

{{ "%.2f"|format(myNumber) }}

That use SprintF this post helped me : [Use sprintf to format floats with no decimal places if integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499579/use-sprintf-to-format-floats-with-no-decimal-places-if-integer)